# Explaining difference between shx and shp files of shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, file-formats

I am searching for a more in depth explanation of the differences in shp and shx files to little avail. I mean beyond the 'shp contain geometry - shx contains an index of the geometry'.

The reason I ask, is because while working in QGIS recently, I have made two observations that led to questions in my mind around the exact differences in these file extentions:

1. QGIS can open and display both shx and shp, and each file appears to be more or less identical in their output (display),
2. but not exactly so - I have noticed that sometimes the matching shx/shp files display slightly 'off-kilter' relative to each other. It doesn't appear to be a projection issue, they simply don't draw in the exact same location as each other.

These observations made me curious as to why these differences in display exist, and why QGIS can open and operate the shx in the same manner as the shp, when previously my understanding was that the shp is the 'master' file if you will, but requires .dbf and .shx to function correctly as a single, whole entity.

Comment: [@Chris](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/123684/chris), have you seen this references [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf), [What are the shapefile files?](https://gisgeography.com/arcgis-shapefile-files-types-extensions/), and [What is a Shapefile?](https://www.gislounge.com/what-is-a-shapefile/).

Comment: Look at [GeospatialPython.com:Generating Shapefile shx Files](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/11/generating-shapefile-shx-files.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The definitive reference on the shapefile format is the [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description](https://support.esri.com/en/white-paper/279).

It is misleading to describe the `shx` as being an "index." Instead, it is the direct access offset file. There is no data in the `shx`, only a clone of the first hundred bytes of the `shp` (with the length block in bytes 24-27 sized for the `shx` length) followed by record number and offset to the starting byte of that record in the `shp`. The only location for attributes is the `dbf` (which is standalone -- despite "knowledge" to the contrary, the `shx` does not tie the `shp` and `dbf`, only record number does that).

It is possible for shapefiles to have "gaps" in the `shp` which make the `shx` indispensible, but in practice Esri tools will rewrite the entire `shp` and `shx` so that any gap created by editing records is removed. Under most conditions, it is possible to recover the `shx` contents if it goes missing; the same cannot be said for the `shp` or `dbf`.

The naming of `shp` and `shx` is an artifact of the `VFILE` variable width direct access module of the PrImeOS operating system, first ported by Esri to Unix, VAX/VMS, Data General, and IBM, then to Microsoft Windows. The `sbn`/`sbx` spatial index pair shares the same naming convention (though these are not documented within the shapefile specification). Within the original `VFILE` FORTRAN library, only the base file was named, and the offset file with an `x` terminal character just appeared at file creation.

Comment: If you search for .shx in that document the first entry is "The suffix for the index file is .shx". It's not a link between the dbf and shp, but as I understand it more like a spatial index.

Comment: And later: `The index file (.shx) contains a 100-byte header followed by 8-byte, fixed-length records. Figure 4 illustrates the index file organization.` Logically it is analogous to database indexes `a data structure that improves the speed of data retrieval operations`.

Comment: No, the `shx` is absolutely **not** a spatial index.

Comment: The `shx` actually slows serial access (more I/O), but it does make direct access *possible*, which could be considered an improvement.

Comment: _"..., only a clone of the first hundred bytes **and record number** and ..."_.   _"... the shx does not tie the shp and dbf, only **record number** does that"_. First you say 'record number' is within .shx. Later you say .shx does not tie .shp and .dbf, but that 'record number' does. If 'record number' ties the two cited formats and it is part of .shx, then why can't it be said .shx ties .shp and .dbf? It is confusing to me this part of your answer. Can you clarify? Tks.

Comment: The record number is present in both `shp` and `shx`. It is **not** present in the `dbf`, only the implicit byte offset from the end of the header records (40 bytes for table, which includes a field count, and 40 additional bytes for each field) times the record size.  I've written shapefile readers and writers in both 'C' and Java, and it is the loop counter variable of the program which links the `shp`/`shx` to the `dbf`. The `shx` provides linkage of record number, by offset with a recno integrity check, to the start of the `shp` record, nothing more.

Answer (score 12):

Shx certainly has nothing to show on a map alone as you can read from the specification https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

You are indeed right in that it is possible to open shapefile by selecting the .shx part with QGIS 3.0.3 but I can't see any difference on the location. I believe that shapefile is still opened through the same path and the result is the same. If you can make a test case for reproducing the issue of different placement of the geometries please create a QGIS ticket about the issue.

If you delete .shp part you'll see that QGIS does not open .shx alone.

Comment: My mistake, I checked the same files again and it was indeed a mismatched projection. When I realigned these, the shx and shp versions of the same layer lined up and were identical as expected. Interestingly, QGIS allows both the .shx and .shp to be uploaded to the same project, and they display their own respective source path, but as pointed out by others, the output is the exact same geometries as these are indeed the same file.

Answer (score 2):

`.shx` is the index for a `.shp` file.

You need both to be able to open the `.shp` file. If you open a `.shx` file in QGIS, it opens the `.shp` file. If they are off, there is a projection issue.

A ShapeFile needs three components:

1. `.shp` - stores the geometry
2. `.shx` - stores the index
3. `.dbf` - stores the attributes

A `.prj` file is usually recommended, which stores the projection information. There can be other files associated with a ShapeFile, but these are not absolutely needed.

Answer (score -1):

The SHX file, an index.  These are stored in binary format. This contains:
File header, identical to that in the SHP file.
Bounding box for each record
The offset to the start of each record, its length, and the number of parts and points.

Comment: Well, no, the file header isn't "identical" (just similar, since the file size is adjusted to the .shx length), and it certainly doesn't store the bounding box for each record, or the number of parts and points.